# How to make one of types mandatory with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have define a type like below

```
export type InputType = {
  configJsonUrl?: string;
  configJsObject?: DataType;
  rawData?: { [key: string]: string }; 
  action?: () => void;
};

export type DataType = {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  'product-configuration': { input: string };
};
```

For the `InputType`, even though all of the 3 values of optional(`configJsonUrl`, `configJsObject` & `rawData`) by themselves, st least one of these should be there in the React Component I am using this type in as shown in the examples below.

```
<ComponentX configJsonUrl='./data/info.json' />);
<ComponentX configJsObject={jsObject} />);
<ComponentX rawData={adhocData} />);
```

How to make one of these mandatory?

I am aware that I can make these mandatory probably like so

```
export type InputType = {
  input: string|DataType|{ [key: string]: string }
  action?: () => void;
};
```

However, I want them to have separate names as well (`configJsonUrl`, `configJsObject` & `rawData`) since I use these names to do some conditional rendering.

How to achieve this? Is it even possible in TS? Please guide.

**Update**
Currently I am doing so in my react component

```
const FormGenerator = ({
  configJsonUrl,
  configJsObject,
  rawData,
}: InputType ): JSX.Element => {
  const [propForForm, setPropForForm] = useState<string>('dummy');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (configJsonUrl) {      
          setPropForForm("URL");
          setLoading(false); // Stop loading
    } else if (rawData) {
          setPropForForm("adhoc object");
          setLoading(false); // Stop loading
   
    } else if (configJsObject) {
          setPropForForm("JS object");
          setLoading(false); // Stop loading      
    }
  }, [configJsonUrl, rawData, configJsObject]);

//rest of the rendering logic
```

**Update2**
Based on suggestions by Bergi , the `InputType` will become

```
export type InputType = {
  input: {configJsonUrl: string} | {configJsObject: DataType} | {rawData: {[key: string]: string}}
action?: () => void;
};
```

The react component will change to

```
const FormGenerator = ({input}: InputType )
//rest of the rendering logic
```

How to access (`configJsonUrl`, `configJsObject` & `rawData`) from the `input`?

Comment: Are you looking for `type InputType = {configJsonUrl: string} | {configJsObject: DataType} | {rawData: {[key: string]: string}};`?

Comment: @Bergi This might work. Now I have added the logic in my react component to the question for more clarity. How do use `InputType` in the react component?  `input[configJsonUrl]` is throwing error `Cannot find name 'configJsonUrl'`.

Comment: It's still [`input.configJsonUrl` or `input["configJsonUrl"]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/1048572) as before with the optional properties. You can also use destructuring. Though for typescript not to complain, you probably first need to check `if ("configJsonUrl" in input)` to distinguish the three input types.

Comment: Earlier the input to react compoent was something like `<ComponentX configJsonUrl='./data/info.json' />);` what would that be now?

Comment: Nothing changes. Why would it? Do you want it to change? Does it no longer work?

Comment: To keep the question simple, I had removed the other items in my `InputType` (for example a function). I have added that now to the question. So, my action input type would be , `type InputType ={ input:  {configJsonUrl: string} | {configJsObject: DataType} | {rawData: {[key: string]: string}}, action?:() => void }.` with this structure,  `<ComponentX configJsonUrl='./data/info.json' />)` is not working . I get the error `Type '{ configJsonUrl: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputType'.`

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to expand your type into three types, each with the single required field and then make your props type be the union of those three *distinct* types:

```js
interface InputFromUrl {
  configJsonUrl: string
}

interface InputFromObject {
  configJsObject: DataType
}

interface InputFromRawData {
  rawData: { [key: string]: string }
}

export type InputType = InputFromUrl | InputFromObject | InputFromRawData;

export type DataType = {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  'product-configuration': { input: string };
};
```

You can *use* `InputType` be checking which key is present in a variable of that type:

```js
declare const props: InputType;

if ('configJsonUrl' in props) {
  props.configJsonUrl // now works
} else if ('configJsObject' in props) {
  props.configJsObject // now works
} else {
  props.rawData // now works
}
```

Comment: How to get hold of `configJsonUrl`, `configJsObject` & `rawData` from within `InputType`? I have added a bit of react component code (where this type is being used) to make things clear.